# Improved Newton method using Bisection method in Python

Tags: python, optimization, newtons-method, bisection

I have write a code which is solving a 2nd order system of nonlinear equations in high dimensional (i=0,N) through the Newton method (Jacobian N+1 * N+1) , having 2 boundary conditions.

I would like to ask you, if I is possible to implement the bisection method in this Ndimensional problem. Unfortunately the Newton convergence does not work on some regions of my problem.

according to this source: http://ursa.as.arizona.edu/~rad/phys305/root_finding/node4.html

"
An improved root finding scheme is to combine the bisection and Newton-Raphson methods. The bisection method guarantees a root (or singularity) and is used to limit the changes in position estimated by the Newton-Raphson method when the linear assumption is poor. However, Newton-Raphson steps are taken in the nearly linear regime to speed convergence.

In other words, if we know that we have a root bracketed between our two bounding points, we first consider the Newton-Raphson step. If that would predict a next point that is outside of our bracketed range, then we do a bisection step instead by choosing the midpoint of the range to be the next point. We then evaluate the function at the next point and, depending on the sign of that evaluation, replace one of the bounding points with the new point. This keeps the root bracketed, while allowing us to benefit from the speed of Newton-Raphson.
"

... is possible to do that in Python in a N dimensional problem?

Rtsafe module of FORTRAN in ndimensional possible do this, and might Matlab has a similar module...

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a sort of homework, you're way better off using [solvers from `scipy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/optimize.html). For a multidimensional problem, have a look at `fsolve` (which uses a modified Newton-Raphson method).

Comment: It is not a homework, it is my research. I dont want someone to write my code or anything else. I am asking for a advise! I cant use scipy solve :D cause this code is more complicated. It uses the Newton multidimensional method ( generalization of the Newton method ) for a number of gridpoints more than 100, to solve a 2nd degree of nonlinear equations with 2 boundary conditions. I am asking if someone knows a way to implement the bidection method in this code, eventually having better convergence, or if she or he knows other method that I could use.
thank you anyway...

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is simple: do not bother implementing own solvers unless absolutely necessary (read: unless available solutions run out of steam).

Comment: Zhenya, the code is not working, because it cant converge! only in specific data that have "normal" calculated u. But, for a other imported data, in which the u at the end should be curved & flat, the Newton m. is not converge! I ask a help or an advice for over-skip this issue. If the problem was in FORTRAN, I would use http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/astrophysik/HEA/internal/Numerical_Recipes/f9-4.pdf RTSAFE module in N dimensions. The question is not if it is necessary to do that. I have to do that! The question is if a multidimensional bisection method could work as an implement on this code!

Comment: if you want to just implement some method from Numerical Recipes which you keep on linking, what exactly is the question you're asking?